# Uncorrected serial upvotes

Tags: discussion, up-votes

I am aware of the issue of chain voting and its reversal process.

However, in recent days I have seen several upvotes within a short time window (max. 2 minutes), 1 vote per post. This always happened at the same time of the day and covers recent posts of mine.

So while this is strange, the algorithm didn't reverse it.

As I am sure that others have noticed the same, it might present a considerable skewing effect on reputation scores. Of course there is the chance, that it is legitimately done by a user who browses my profile and then reads some of my recent posts. But nevertheless it should be looked into.

Comment: What's a "short time window"? Minutes? Hours?

Comment: I just checked and these votes usually all happen within about 2 minutes.

Comment: That's weird then. If you've acquired a "fan" I'd expect the votes to be more sporadic.

Comment: The time was different on different days though. On one day I also got 8 votes within 2 minutes, and then only 6 of them were reversed.. so, yes, strange.

Comment: Pretty sure no one regularily looking on Meta EE.SE will be able to act on this (even the mods). You might have better chance on the Main Meta, but I seem to remember that in this specific case, the recommended course of action is to directly contact the StackExchange staff through the "contact form" (the appropriate link is on the web page footer).

Comment: I do not see what the problem is with a string of upvotes. Can someone point me to the logic?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for highlighting this. As *dim* said, mods can't fix this directly. However a situation has been under review, so you have added useful info.

If you have (or plan to) contact SE about this directly, please let us know, so that the mods don't duplicate effort escalating it as well. However if you want to leave it with us, then again, please let us know, and I will put the (complicated :( ) situation higher up on my "mod to-do list", now that we have more info.

Comment: Thank you for taking time and explaining me the situation Sam. I did not and don't plan to report this issue anywhere else. Feel free to escalate it