# How come people upvote a bunch of a member's answers rapid fire style?

Tags: discussion, up-votes

What is going on when someone (I assume just one person) suddenly goes through a bunch of my answers and upvotes all of them? For what purpose?

Comment: Also see this: https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/uncorrected-serial-upvotes. Anyway, the mods seem to be aware.

Comment: Looks like this is happening to many users these days ...

Comment: Maybe they like your answers! What annoys me is somewhat different. I post a trivial answer to a trivial question and suddenly get loads of upvotes. I answer a difficult question and silence

Answer (score 2):

As a new user I sometimes did the same, when I saw a great answer by a user I was not yet familiar with. Chances are that the same user has written a lot of other great answers on similar topics, and reading them can be educational.

After a while it gets boring, and you tend to recognize most high-rep users. You also learn about serial down- *and* up-voting, and the bots/mods/machines searching for it.

Comment: I occasionallyt look at a users answers and may upvote a number of them if worthwhile. Less likely with high rep users. Usually its because attention has been drawn to them which may indicate a closer look is a good idea. In my case it hasn't happened with you :-).